# How to find the min and max values of a csv file based on a different column of dates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a csv file that consists of temperature values in 2 minute intervals for 3 months. First 5 lines can be seen below.

```
    T1C T2C T1-T2C  U1  U2  Date    year    month   day
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2020-04-25  2020    4   25
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2020-04-25  2020    4   25
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2020-04-25  2020    4   25
3   8,932   6,703   2,229   0,018   0,018   2020-04-25  2020    4   25
4   9,083   6,799   2,284   0,018   0,018   2020-04-25  2020    4   25
```

I want to get the max values in T1C and lowest values in T2C for each day. Should I do this with groupby, I couldn't think of a way to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to make a loop. For each iteration, you replace value if it is smaller (T2C) or larger (T1C) than the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
result = df.groupby('Date').agg({'T1C': 'max', 'T2C': 'min'})
```

Comment: Will probably want to ensure that T1C and T2C are actually numeric values... they look like they're likely strings in the example

Comment: Thanks this did the job, but for some reason I am getting an 'inf' value for the minimum, can it be because of there is negative values?

Answer (score 1):

I will groupby `Day` and then aggregate:

```
df.groupby('day').agg({'T1C': 'max', 'T2C': 'min'})
```

Comment: Yes this helped, but I am getting an 'inf' value for the minimum. Any idea why?